# How to show visually values from an array inside another component in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue app where I send one array from one component to another. which works. But now I want to visually show this. What I mean is like this:

Array 1 has the field date and time inside it which is copied to the parent Array 2 I can log this but if I want to show a specific value for example date itself it does not show anything and gives the error the property can not be read. I tried looping through the parent array but it did not work causing in the can not read property error.

Could someone give me a pointer on how to fix this.

Childcomponent method and array to be copied the method fills the array here with data:

```
data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],

    dates: [{date : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10), time: []}],
   
  }),

  methods:{
      addTimeFields(){

        this.selectedTime.push({
          startTime:"",
          endTime: "",
        })
        this.dates[0].time.push(
        this.selectedTime
          )

      },
```

Parent component which should get the array here I am trying to push the array from child to parent array which works (save method) but when I try to loop though it gives me an error:

```
 <v-card-text v-for="(i,index) in finalDate">
      <v-btn >
        {{i.finalDate}}
      </v-btn>

    </v-card-text>

    <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer />

      <v-col>
        <vs-button>Generate Meeting Link</vs-button>

      </v-col>
      {{finalDate}}
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import MeetingsTableComponent from "@/components/MeetingsTableComponent";
import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";

export default {
  name: "NextMeetingCardComponent",
  components: { DatePickerComponent },
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    finalDate: [],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false
  }),

  methods:{
    save() {
      this.finalDate.push(
        this.$refs.datepicker.dates
      )

    }
```

Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "date" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <NextMeetingCardComponent>
       <DashboardComponent> at src/views/DashboardComponent.vue
         <VMain>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a random {{ date }} in your component:

```
 <v-card-text v-for="(i,index) in finalDate">
      <v-btn >
        {{i.date}}
      </v-btn>

    </v-card-text>

    <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer />

      <v-col>
        <vs-button>Generate Meeting Link</vs-button>

      </v-col>
      {{date}} <---- HERE
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Could this be the issue?

Comment: oh no before posting it I had change the date you see there to finalDate but it did not work before the change either. I will edit my question, thanks

Comment: so the error would also then refer to "finalDate"?

Comment: yes I am pushing the elements of the child array to the finalDate array in the parrent component and looping through it